# Apply options to a specific chosen select element

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to apply these 2 options for a specific `chosen-select` element:
`display_selected_options: false, display_disabled_options: false`, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I tried: `$('#chosenElement').chosen({ display_selected_options: false, display_disabled_options: false });`.

This however does work but gets applied to all chosen elements: `$('.chosen-select').chosen({ display_selected_options: false, display_disabled_options: false });`.

What am I missing?

EDIT: rendered `html`:

```
    <select class="chosen-select" data-container="body" data-placement="top"
     data-toggle="tooltip" id="chosenElement" multiple="multiple" 
name="chosenElement" title=""><option value="2">FFFF</option>
        <option value="3">AAAAA</option>
        <option value="1">BBBBB</option>
        <option value="6">CCCCC</option>
        <option value="5">DDDDD</option>
        <option value="4">EEEE</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: It would be good to place at least a part of HTML code.

Comment: Done, see edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the options of a chosen element by id works fine. Just make sure that the options are not reset later(using class selector).

```
$('#chosenElement').chosen({ display_selected_options: true, display_disabled_options: false });
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/kvVCE/3/).

Comment: The `chosen-select` element is at start disabled. Could that be it? It would be strange though, because `$('.chosen-select').chosen({ display_selected_options: false, display_disabled_options: false });` works either way.

Comment: Yes thats the problem because you can't call `.chosen` twice on the same element. (the first settings that you set will remain)

Comment: Can't believe I wasted 4 hours on this because they decided not to document this!

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the id of the select, you could use the following:

```
$(".chosen-select").each(function() { // Loop through all selects with the class 'chosen-select'.
    var options = {}; // Set options to an empty object initially
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id && id == "chosenElement") { // Check if the select id is the one you want. If so, set the properties below.
        options.display_selected_options = false;
        options.display_disabled_options = false;
    }
    $(this).chosen(options); // Finally call chosen on the select, passing in options as an argument.
});
```